# Convert SQL-query with CAST() to HQL

Tags: mysql, hql

Please help me to write HQL query for the following SQL query:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING([columnname], 6) AS UNSIGNED))+1 
FROM [Tablename] 
WHERE DistrCode = [(value)];
```

Comment: It is working in mysql fine but in the form of hql query it is not working.   I hope u understand

Comment: Please divide your questions into sub parts. Like do you know which part is not working-> here is an idea try max, cast, substring separately and see what is the problem. And check these links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791325/how-do-i-write-hql-query-with-cast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121520/hql-substring-last-x-characters

Comment: i checked those links before posting this.   Mr.jan's answer works perfectly

Comment: @GV : I guess , Minaz is simply asking you to ask a more clear question as what you tried and what challenges you facing. +1 since you are new & don't wish to discourage you due to negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot try it myself, but just from searching around I found these probable solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING([columnname], 6) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER))+1
```

**Solution 2**

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING([columnname], 6) AS INTEGER))+1
```

Maybe you can try both and report back, which one worked.